# Is every positive semidefinite matrix the Gramian of a matrix over the same ring?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

The *Gramian* of a complex matrix $A$ is $A^\ast A$. The equation
$$
\langle \boldsymbol{x}, A^\ast A\boldsymbol{x}\rangle
= \langle A\boldsymbol{x}, A\boldsymbol{x}\rangle=\lVert A\boldsymbol{x}\rVert^2\geq 0
$$
tells us that Gramians are positive semidefinite.

The converse is also true. The spectral theorem implies that every positive semidefinite matrix $H$ factors as
$$
H=UDU^\ast
$$
where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal with nonnegative entries. Defining $A=\sqrt{D}U^\ast$ then gives $H=A^\ast A$.

For example, consider the factorization
$$
\overset{H}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
2 & -2 & 8
\end{array}\right]}
=\overset{U}{
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}  & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{2}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
\frac{4}{\sqrt{18}}  & 0 & -\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right]
}
\overset{D}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
9 &  & \\
 & 1 &  \\
  &  & 0
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{U^\ast}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} & \frac{4}{\sqrt{18}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right]}
$$
It follows that $H=A^\ast A$ where $A$ is given by
$$
\overset{A}{
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
}
=
\overset{\sqrt{D}}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]}
\overset{U^\ast}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}} & \frac{4}{\sqrt{18}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right]}
$$
It's worth observing that our original $H$ had entries in $\Bbb Z$ but this $A$ does not have integer entries.

However, in this example it is possible to write $H=A^\ast A$ where $A$ does have integer entries
$$
\overset{H}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \\
2 & -2 & 8
\end{array}\right]}=\overset{A^\ast}{\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
2 & -2
\end{array}\right]}\overset{A}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -2
\end{array}\right]}
$$
With this context in mind, here are my questions.

1. Suppose $H$ is $n\times n$ positive semidefinite with entries in a subring $R$ of $\Bbb C$. Can we write $H=A^\ast A$ where $A$ is $m\times n$ with entries in $R$? If so, is there a way to construct $A$?
2. More precisely, let $R$ be a subring of $\Bbb C$ and let $\mathcal{P}_n(R)$ be the collection of $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrices with entries in $R$. Is there an equality
   $$
   \mathcal{P}_n(R)=\bigcup_{i=1}^k\{A^\ast A\mid A\in\mathcal{M}_{i\times n}(R)\}
   $$
   for some $n\leq k\leq\infty$?
3. If this factorization is not possible, are there conditions on $R$ where the factorization is possible?

Comment: I don't think so. You do get additional wiggle room when allowing higher dimension vectors http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/E7.html  There was a question on this, years ago, on MO. I'll try to find it.

Comment: By "higher dimension vectors" are you referring to the size of $A$? I'm curious if there's an answer if there aren't restrictions on the size of $A$.

Comment: Yes. An extreme example, if you have a Gram matrix that is one by one, single positive entry $n$ that is not a square or the sum of two or three integer squares. However, it is automatically the sum of four integer squares, so it is the product of a row vector of four entries and its transpose.

Comment: @WillJagy I was hoping this question would receive more attention. I searched around on overflow and didn't see anything related. Do you think it would be appropriate to ask there?

Comment: Brian, yes, I think so. The question I had in mind (and cannot find) had root lattices for Lie algebras, the question was, for an $n$ dimensional integral lattice, so Gram matrix integers and positive definite, could we always arrange a "basis" of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb Z^{n+1}$ or maybe    $\mathbb Z^{n+2}.$ I seem to recall the conclusion was negative in general, although we can make such an arrangement for many examples. For example, take two vectors $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,0,1),$ the Gram matrix matches $x^2 + xy + y^2$ (well, doubled).